# Silverlight TreeView KeepSelected .. How?

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

Silverlight TreeView doesnt have KeepSelected method as in Winforms.

When TreeView loses focus - the selection isnt visible however the items is still selected..

I'd like to preserve selection visual even if TreeView lost its focus.

Anyone tryied to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom style or template for the treeview node, so that it would display the color of selected item as per your choice even when it is out of focus.

Comment: yeah that was my thought too. but was hoping to get some other ideas.. will wait couple of days.. thanks!